# Jquery Grid Search Event - how to force reload of Grid

Tags: jquery, ajax, search, jqgrid, reload

I have a jquery grid with a search box on top of it.

```
Search: <input type="text" value="" id="searchInput" placeholder="Enter Document Type"/>
```

In the Search Keystroke event, everything works fine until the user enters a string that returns no values. Then the grid shows its usual 'no records found'. From this point on, the Search is broken.

I've researched why and found that the postData object/property no longer contains the original ajax-returned grid rows. So subsequent searches are trying to filter against an empty grid.

How do I force a reload of my grid at this point (where location.reload() is) ? Reload of page doesn't do it since this is partial page and that forces user back into a previous page with no grid.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document)
    .ready(function() {
        'use strict';

        showWebTour();

       getAllAttachments();

       $('#searchInput')
            .on('change keyup paste',
                function() {
                    var searchtext = $(this).val();
                    var grid = $('#documentList');

                    if ($("#documentList tr").length == 0 && searchtext.length == 0) {
                        location.reload();
                    }
                    var postdata = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData');
                    // BUG: When Search returns no records, postData no longer exists so next search always fails
                    var myfilter = {
                        groupOp: "OR",
                        rules: []
                    };
                    myfilter.rules.push({
                        field: "DocumentType",
                        op: "cn",
                        data: searchtext
                    });

                    $.extend(postdata,
                    {
                        filters: myfilter
                    });
                    $("#gbox_documentList").show();
                    if ($('#empty-documentList', $('#gbox_documentList').parent()).length) {
                        $('#empty-documentList', $('#gbox_documentList').parent()).remove();
                    }
                    grid.jqGrid('setGridParam',
                    {
                        search: searchtext.length > 2,
                        postData: postdata
                    });
                    grid.trigger("reloadGrid",
                    [
                        {
                            page: 1
                        }
                    ]);

                });

    });


function getAllAttachments() {

    if (typeof ($('#refreshDocs') != 'undefined')) {
        $('#refreshDocs').off('click');
    }

    $.ajax({
        url:
            '@Url.Action("AttactmentViewDocuments", "Document")?databaseId=@Model.LoanIdentifier.DatabaseId&loanRecordId=@Model.LoanIdentifier.LoanId',
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'GET',
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('.all-documents-loading')
                    .css({
                        "display": "block"
                    });
            $('.attached-documents-loading')
                               .css({
                                   "display": "block"
                               });
            $('.generated-documents-loading')
                             .css({
                                 "display": "block"
                             });
        },
        success: function (data) {
            bindDocumentList(data.GridData);
            $('.jqgfirstrow').hide();
        },
        error: function(xhr, response, status) {

            /* Let user know that could not load data  */
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('.all-documents-loading')
                    .css({
                        "display": "none"
                    });
            $('.attached-documents-loading')
                               .css({
                                   "display": "none"
                               });
            $('.generated-documents-loading')
                             .css({
                                 "display": "none"
                             });
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: can you explain how the search work, does it generate new data from database or is filtering on client side

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
  $("#gridContactDetails").jqGrid().setGridParam({ datatype: 'local' }).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

OR
if return type is json

```
    $("#gridContactDetails").jqGrid().setGridParam({ datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

**#gridContactDetails - change the id**